# Need To Create A Help component in Android

Tags: android, listview

I am building an Android application and would like to include a help component in it. The Help module would have a structure as shown below :

HELP

- FAQs
- Features

  - Placing Orders

    - Online Ordering
    - Mobile Application based Ordering
    - Phone Ordering
  - Managing my Loyalty Account

    - Signup
    - Points Catalog
    - Loyalty Status Tracking
    - Points Redemption
  - Accessing Order History

    - Purchase History
    - Insights
    - Reports
  - Setting Reminders
- Helpline

As far as i could find, there are two ways of doing this kind of structure.

The first way would be to use a  Multi-level ListView. The problem with this is that the code is quite complicated and that usually ListViews have equal number of child nodes. For example :- in the above mentioned layout "Features" has several children whereas "FAQs" has none. How would that work in a List View?

---

The Second Method is to use Buttons for all the first-level options and then create individual activity pages for each of the corresponding children. So the first page called "Help" would have 3 buttons as shown :-

HELP

- FAQs
- Features
- Helpline

Upon clicking any one, a new page would open with either more buttons or some text; depending on what the user clicks.

My question is, which of the above two methods is better suited to my application? If there is another way to do this than the two i've mentioned I'd be happy to hear about that as well. I thank you for your time and patience in helping me.

Comment: We use WebView with nicely designed HTML document.

Comment: Another vote for WebView and some .html files in your assets folder (and come css files to make it prettier)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this open source project to create a `TreeListView`:

https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following structure:

The HELP Activity will contain 3 tabs

- **FAQ** can contain the ListView of questions.
- **Features** can contain the ListView with [Section Deviders](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html): Placing Orders, Managing my Loyalty Account etc.
- **Helpline** can contain e.g. text and image.

This structure can be created using Eclipse [Activities templates](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html): Tabs or Tabs + Swipe or Swipe Views + Title Strip.